# How to find (numerical) value of a derivative at point?

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis, operators

I have the following function:

```
f[0, 0] = 0
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)^(-1)]
```

How do I find its partial derivatives at any given point, including $(0,0)$?  This doesn't work (obviously, I guess):

```
point={0,0}
D[f[x, y], x] /. x -> point[[1]] /. y -> point[[2]]
```

Comment: `f[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)^(-1)]`
`point = {1, 1};`
`D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> point[[1]], y -> point[[2]]}`

This worked..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you have any problems, I recommend using the `Derivative` operator instead of `D`, since the latter works on expressions, while the former one can work on pure functions.

```
{Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y], Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The subtlety here is that one cannot use it to find partial derivatives of `f` at `{0,0}`, e.g.

```
Derivative[0, 1][f][0, 0]
```

> ```
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression E^ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered. >>
>
> Indeterminate
> ```

however, you can use `Limit` instead of `Derivative`:

```
Limit[ #, h -> 0] & /@ {( f[0 + h, 0] - f[0, 0] )/ h, ( f[0, 0 + h] - f[0, 0] )/ h}
```

> ```
> {0, 0}
> ```

In general, it works as we would like:

```
Limit[ #, h -> 0] & /@ { (f[x + h, y] - f[x, y])/ h, (f[x, y + h] - f[x, y])/ h} ==
{ Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y], Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] }
```

> ```
> True
> ```

One can also take advantage of `FoldList` to follow computing several limits, e.g. :

```
FoldList[ Limit, (f[x + h, y] - f[x, y])/h, {h -> 0, y -> 0, x -> 0}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

We have shown that the partial derivative with respect to `x` is continuous at `{0,0}`. 
We can show much more; namely, that any derivative of any order vanishes at `{0,0}`. We find here the few first terms of a Taylor series expansion near `{0,0}` :

```
Limit[ Limit[ Normal @ Series[ f[x, y], {y, y0, 7}, {x, x0, 7}], x0 -> 0], y0 -> 0]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

i.e. this function is not analytic at `{0,0}`, since the Taylor series expansion is identically `0`, while the function `f` itself is not.

Comment: Thanks, but formally, this is the *limit of the derivative as the point tends to zero*, not exactly the *derivative at zero* (though in this case they are equal).  Do I have to resort to `Limit` and the definition of a derivative to do it in the general case?

Comment: You can find the `Limit` of the difference ratio directly.

Comment: Exactly, I just thought there's another way.

Comment: @mbork more exactly `f` is a smooth function everywhere  but it is not analytic in `{0,0}`.

Answer (score 3):

For evaluating derivatives for numerical arguments, one (somewhat neglected) function for the purpose is `SeriesCoefficient[]`. Of course, this produces derivatives scaled by factorials, so you have to multiply by the appropriate factorial factors to get the actual value of the derivative. For instance,

```
Derivative[3, 5][Function[{x, y}, Exp[-1/(x^2 + y^2)]]][1, 1]
   117215/(256 Sqrt[E])

With[{p = 3, q = 5, x0 = 1, y0 = 1}, 
     p! q! SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-1/(x^2 + y^2)], {x, x0, p}, {y, y0, q}]]
   117215/(256 Sqrt[E])
```