# How to speed up drawing a tangent plane?

Tags: manipulate, performance-tuning

I have this code to produce an interactive visualization of a tangent plane to a function:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 2*y^3
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]],
  Plot3D[f[point[[1]], point[[2]]] +
    Limit[(f[point[[1]] + h, point[[2]]] - f[point[[1]], point[[2]]])/
       h, h -> 0]*(x - point[[1]]) +
    Limit[(f[point[[1]], point[[2]] + h] - f[point[[1]], point[[2]]])/
       h, h -> 0]*(y - point[[2]]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8], MeshStyle -> Gray]],
 {{point, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

It is, however, extremely slow.  I suspect that the reason is that I unnecessarily compute the partial derivatives over and over again inside the second `Plot3D`, so my question is: how to change it?

Note: I am using the above code also for other functions as [discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11278/how-to-find-numerical-value-of-a-derivative-at-point), and that is the reason for the `Limit` in computation of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 5):

Simply move the derivative computation outside the scope of the `Manipulate`, using either `D` or `Limit`.

```
f[x_, y_] = x^3 + 2 y^3;
fx[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x];
fx[x_, y_] = Limit[(f[x + h, y] - f[x, y])/h, h -> 0];
fy[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], y];
fy[x_, y_] = Limit[(f[x, y + h] - f[x, y])/h, h -> 0]
Manipulate[
 x0 = p[[1]]; y0 = p[[2]];
 Show[{
   Plot3D[{f[x, y], 
     f[x0, y0] + fx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + fy[x0, y0] (y - y0)},
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-25, 25}},
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.6]], 
      Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.6]]},
    ViewPoint -> {2.5, -2, 1}, ClippingStyle -> None],
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], 
     Point[{p[[1]], p[[2]], f[p[[1]], p[[2]]]}]}]
   }],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {2, 2}}]
```

Comment: Interesting.  Why do you provide two rules for `fx[x_,y_]`?

Comment: @mbork Either definition works, although the second clearly overwrites the first. I was simply trying to emphasize the fact that you can use either the built in `D` operator or the `Limit` definition, as you indicated that you might need to.

Comment: OK, thanks.  For the moment I thought that somehow the `Limit` one is chosen if the `D` doesn't work (e.g., when the function is given by a separate rule for one point).  And thanks for the nicety - the large point!  (I did it using a one-element list in `ListPointPlot3D`, definitely less elegant.)

Comment: @mbork you could also show the `Point`s using [Epilog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html)

Comment: @Simon `Epilog` is really for 2D graphics. From the documentation: "In three-dimensional graphics, two-dimensional graphics primitives can be specified by the Epilog option. The graphics primitives are rendered in a 0,1 coordinate system."  - Hence, the `Show[{Plot3D[__], Graphics3D[__]}]` construct.

Comment: @Mark Oops, my bad! I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @Simon I've fallen for that one myself!

Answer (score 4):

The limits can be calculated analytically one time and then used inside your `Manipulate`. You can use `With` to place the final expression where you need them:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 2*y^3;
With[{l1 = Limit[(f[px + h, py] - f[px, py])/h, h -> 0], 
  l2 = Limit[(f[px, py + h] - f[px, py])/h, h -> 0]},
 Manipulate[
  {px, py} = point;
  Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]], 
   Plot3D[f[point[[1]], point[[2]]] + l1*(x - point[[1]]) + 
     l2*(y - point[[2]]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
    MeshStyle -> Gray]], {{point, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just discovered `With` myself, too, but I've put it inside `Show`; I guess this doesn't make much difference.