# Numerical partial derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

For a one-variable numerical function, it's simple to calculate the derivative at a point with `Derivative` as [Szabolcs has pointed out before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14463):

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := x^2
f'[3.]
(* 6. *)
```

But this fails for partial derivatives:

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] = x y z + x^2 y^2 z

Derivative[1, 0, 0][g][1., 1., 1.]
(* 3. *)

Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.]
(* Unevaluated: Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.] *)
```

[`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html) seems to only handle the one-dimensional case.

[Using `SeriesCoefficient`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11313) simply returns the (scaled) `Derivative` expression:

```
SeriesCoefficient[g[x, y, z], {x, 2., 1}, {y, 3., 1}, {z, 4., 1}]
(* Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.] *)
```

I'd prefer not to clutter my code with finite difference formulas, since this functionality must be in *Mathematica* somewhere; where is it?

**EDIT:** The closest I've found so far is [`` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html), but that works on grids and it's a hassle to use for other purposes. Anyone know of a convenient C/Java library that links well with *Mathematica* and handles all kinds of numerical differentiation?

**EDIT2:** Does `Derivative` have accuracy control? (step size or anything)

```
Clear @ f
f[x_?NumericQ] = Exp[x];
Array[Abs[Derivative[#1][f][1.] - E] &, {8}]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 \text{n} & \text{seconds} & \text{error} \\
 \hline 
 5 & 0.123 & 6.77\times 10^{-7} \\
 6 & 0.297 & 0.0000484 \\
 7 & 0.592 & 0.0127 \\
 8 & 1.05 & 1.11 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: as an aside, the code for `ND` is freely visible (it's in `AddOns/Packages/NumericalCalculus/NLimit.m`).

Comment: Related question: [How can I differentiate Numerically?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14404/245)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no fundamental problem in using `ND` to answer all your questions. First I'll repeat the definition of your example function, then I do a single and a third partial derivative. Following that, I'll repeat the test of the accuracy  for the exponential function:

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] = x y z + x^2 y^2 z

(* ==> x y z + x^2 y^2 z *)

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

ND[g[x, 1, 1], x, 1]

(* ==> 3. *)

ND[ND[ND[g[x, y, z], x, 1], y, 1], z, 1]

(* ==> 5. *)

Clear@f
f[x_?NumericQ] = Exp[x];
Array[Abs[
   ND[f[x], {x, #}, 1, WorkingPrecision -> 40, Terms -> 10] - 
    E] &, {8}]

(*
==> {2.29368416218483*10^-21, 9.0878860135398*10^-19, 
 3.069047503987*10^-17, 3.9592354955*10^-16, 3.03377341*10^-15, 
 1.671999*10^-14, 7.334*10^-14, 2.7*10^-13}
*)
```

The last example with the exponential function is actually discussed specifically in the help for [`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html), and I just copied the settings from that application.

**Edit**

With the nested `ND` calls above, the number of evaluations of the function `g` may become prohibitively large. Here is a way to reduce the number of derivative evaluations dramatically when doing repeated partial derivatives with `ND`:

```
Clear[g, g1, g2];
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := (c += 1; x y z + x^2 y^2 z)
g1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := ND[g[x1, y, z], x1, x]
g2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := ND[g1[x, y1, z], y1, y]

c = 0;
(* ==> 0 *)

ND[g2[1, 1, z], z, 1] // N
(* ==> 5. *)

c
(* ==> 512 *)
```

The variable `c` is just a counter that gets incremented whenever the original function `g` is called. Compared to `ND[Nd[Nd[...]]]`, the reduction factor is `256`.

Comment: The problem with nesting `ND` is that it becomes incredibly inefficient, `ND[ND[ND[g[x, y, z], x, 1], y, 1], z, 1]` evaluates the function 131072 times(!)

Comment: Yes, numerical differentiation is known to be sensitive to cancellation errors, so this is to be expected.

Comment: @ssch See my edited answer, it's a lot faster...

Comment: @Jens,  does MMA derivative and ACEGEN derivative work better?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM It's certainly an alternative. Maybe it helps to look at the discussion below [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14421/245) where Automatic Differentiation is mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.  You have a symbolic base function and numeric top-level one.

```
g0[x_, y_, z_] := x y z + x^2 y^2 z;
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := g0[x, y, z];

Derivative[nn__][g][x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Derivative[nn][g0][x, y, z]

Derivative[1, 0, 0][g][1., 1., 1.]
(* 3. *)

Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.]
(* 25. *)
```

One caveat: Somehow the rule is associated to `Derivative` not `g`.  Clearing `g` doesn't unset the rule:

```
Clear[g];
Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.]
(* 25. *)
```

Clearing `Derivative` does:

```
Clear[Derivative];
Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.]
(* Derivative[1, 1, 1][g][2., 3., 4.] *)
```

(No complaints from *Mathematica*, and `Derivative` still works.)

Comment: Nice, sadly I don't have it in symbolic form :(

Comment: What form do you have `g` in?

Comment: In this case a linked in C function. Sometimes I have symbolic ones where `D` is prohibitively expensive (minutes) although in those cases I often get by with computing it once and storing that expression to plug numerical values in when needed.