# Numeric calculation of Hessian

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

I want to calculate the Hessian matrix for a function that can only be evaluated numerically. So far, I have the following (where f is just for testing):

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

np = 3;  (* number of parameters *)
f0[{x_, y_, z_}] := x^2*y*z^3 + z + 1
(* numeric version; c to count evaluations *)
f[{pars__?NumericQ}] := (c += 1; f0[{pars}])

(* construct symmetric hessian *)
hessian[{pars__?NumericQ}] := Module[{diag, urt, temp1, temp2},
   (* diagonal *)
   diag = Table[
     ND[f[ReplacePart[{pars}, i -> temp1]], {temp1, 
       2}, {pars}[[i]]], {i, 1, np}
     ];
   (* upper right triangle *)
   urt = Table[
     If[j > i,
      ND[ND[f[ReplacePart[{pars}, {i -> temp1, j -> temp2}]], 
        temp1, {pars}[[i]]], temp2, {pars}[[j]]],
      0
      ],
     {i, 1, np}, {j, 1, np}
     ];
   (* result *)
   Table[
    If[i == j, diag[[i]],
     If[j > 1,
      urt[[i, j]],
      urt[[j, i]]
      ]
     ],
    {i, 1, np}, {j, 1, np}
    ]
   ];
```

This seems to work:

```
 c = 0;
 hessian[{3, 4, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

yields the expected result. But the number of function evaluations appears to be rather large (I got c = 3099). Is this normal for ND, or can the above calculation be improved?

Thank you for any answers/comments.

Comment: The culprit is `ND[ND[f[..]..]..]` -- the inside `ND` especially, for which the `j`-th parameter `temp2` is not numeric. I don't have an solution, yet, though.

Comment: Closely related: [Numerical partial derivative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22370/245)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment the culprit is the nested `ND` in `ND[ND[f[..],..],..]`.  The inside `ND` is of the form below.  The function `g` below (`f` in your code) does not evaluate to a numerical result because at least one of the arguments remains a symbol.  `ND` returns an expression that can be used, but it has 128 function calls to `g` in it.

```
g[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] := (foo++; x0 + y0 + z0);
Count[ND[g[x, y, 2.], x, 1.], _g, Infinity]
(* 128 *)
```

With a normal numeric function, `ND` does eight evaluations:

```
foo = 0;
ND[g[x, 1., 2.], x, 1.]
foo
(* 1. *)
(* 8  *)
```

So for a mixed partial derivative, one might hope for 64 evaluations from nested `ND`.  One might hope for better since second order, non-mixed partials require 9 function evaluations. The numerical calculus package does not provide such methods, and I don't know if they exist. Mixed partials are higher dimensional and estimating them may be intrinsically more difficult.

The key is to prevent `ND` from being evaluated until the function has all numeric arguments. To do that we set up partial derivative functions that hold up evaluation of `ND` until they have all numeric arguments. This can be done using [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) to associate such a partial derivative of `f` with an ["upvalue"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html) of `f`.

```
c = 0;
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
Clear[f, fx, fy, fz, f0, x, y, z];
f0[{x_, y_, z_}] := x^2*y*z^3 + z + 1
f[{x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}] := (c++; f0[{x0, y0, z0}]);

fx[{x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}] := ND[f[{x, y0, z0}], x, x0];
ND[f[{x_Symbol, y_Symbol, z_} | {x_Symbol, y_, z_Symbol}], x_, x0_?NumericQ] ^:=
   fx[{x0, y, z}];

fy[{x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}] := ND[f[{x0, y, z0}], y, x0];
ND[f[{x_Symbol, y_Symbol, z_} | {x_, y_Symbol, z_Symbol}], y_, y0_?NumericQ] ^:=
   fy[{x, y0, z}];

fz[{x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}] :=  ND[f[{x0, y0, z}], z, z0];
ND[f[{x_Symbol, y_, z_Symbol} | {x_, y_Symbol, z_Symbol}], z_, z0_?NumericQ] ^:=
   fz[{x, y, z0}];
```

Then the number of function calls is reduce to 219 = 3 x 64 + 3 x 9 (according to the two kinds of second-order partial derivatives, mixed and non-mixed):

```
c = 0;
hessian[{3, 4, 5}] // MatrixForm
c
(* 1000.  750.  1800.
   750.     0.   675.
   1800.    0   1080.  *)
(* 219 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvement and explanation. I wasn't aware of the UpSetDelayed command. This should be quite useful.

Comment: Did you forget to define the hessian in your answer? Or is it just me?

Comment: @chris Use the OP's `hessian`.  I left it out because it was long.  (Hope that's ok.)

Comment: @Michael E2 would it be possible to generalize your answer to `np` dimensions? Also, how can I use the OP's `hessian` if `fx` etc are not defined?

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, here's what I wrote for myself. (It doesn't use ND.)

```
NHessian::usage = "NHessian[f, x] computes a numerical approximation \
to the Hessian matrix evaluated at f[x]. NHessian take the option \
Scale, which can be a scalar or a vector (matching the length of the \
vector x). The default value is Scale -> \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \
\(-3\)]\)."

Options[NHessian] = {Scale -> 10^-3}

NHessian[f_, x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), opts___?OptionQ] :=
Module[{n, h, norm, z, mat, f0},
n = Length[x];
h = Scale /. {opts} /. Options[NHessian];
norm = If[VectorQ[h], Outer[Times, 2 h, 2 h], 4 h^2];
z = If[VectorQ[h], DiagonalMatrix[h], h*IdentityMatrix[n]];
mat = ConstantArray[0., {n, n}];
f0 = f[x];
Do[
    mat[[i, j]] =
        If[i == j,
        (* then *)
            .5 (f[x + 2 * z[[i]]] - 2 f0 + f[x - 2 * z[[i]]]),
        (* else *)
            f[x + z[[i]] + z[[j]]] - f[x + z[[i]] - z[[j]]] - 
                f[x - z[[i]] + z[[j]]] + f[x - z[[i]] - z[[j]]]
        ],
{i, n}, {j, i, n}
];
(mat + Transpose[mat])/norm
]
```

Let's apply this to the given function:

```
f0[{x_, y_, z_}] := (c++; x^2*y*z^3 + z + 1)

c = 0;
NHessian[f0, {3, 4, 5}]\\MatrixForm
c
(* 1000.  750.  1800.
    750.    0.   675.
   1800.  675.  1080.  *)
(* 19 *)
```

Comment: Really nice. This is an even faster solution. Many thanks.

Comment: I liked the simplicity of this solution! Would it make sense to use as default for `Scale` something proportional to the vector `vec` at which the Hessian is being evaluated? Eg, `Scale->Abs[vec] 10^-5`.