# Numeric mixed derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

**In short**

I need *NumericCalculus`ND* extended to mixed partial derivatives. This can be done by nesting them, but care has to be taken to evaluate underling ND only when the parameters become numeric. There are examples in the answers on ["Numerical partial derivative"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24420/2036) and ["Numeric calculation of Hessian"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28950/2036) (make sure to notice the discussion on the efficiency). The challenge is to build such patterns with arbitrary number of parameters.

**Long story**

I am forced to take the derivative of my 200k leafcount expressions numerically. I am aware of *NumericCalculus`ND* which works great, but does not allow mixed derivatives. There are some examples on how to do it efficiently in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24420/2036) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28950/2036) answer. I would like to play around with a greater number of parameters and use a `Scale` option for each of them. So I would like to have a nice top level function.

An example of what I would like it to be capable of:

```
nd[Sin[x Conjugate[y]] Cos[u v] /.{u->u0, v->v0}, {x, x0}, {y, y0}, Scale -> {xScale, yScale}]
```

To define such a function with variable number of parameters and understanding the syntax in some of the examples is beyond my capabilities. Could someone provide the function? It is a pity that *Mathematica* does not ship with one.

**Update to the long story:**
Both of the related answers I linked discuss how the underling ND should be called only, when all parameters are finally numeric. This avoids big number of ND calls with partially numeric expressions. I would like the method to have the same feature and not just nesting the ND calls.

**Update 2**
As I did not consider it relevant, I did not mention that I have complex variables. In this case [finite difference method is ill defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Complex_variable_methods) and some simple reimplementation of ND would not do.

Comment: The _Mathematica_ code in your example contains a syntax error -- `Sin[x y*] `. This makes it hard to understand what you actually want. Please correct your example.

Comment: Related: [Numeric calculation of Hessian](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28948/numeric-calculation-of-hessian), [Numerical partial derivative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/numerical-partial-derivative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial answer

I have similar situation (but I numerically compute only first derivatives) and found that the most reliable and efficient solution is do not rely on `ND` but implement numerical derivatives by yourself using the definition

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

Such approach requires at the first step finding optimal $h$ for each of the parameters which gives maximum precision. It cannot be too small because in this case the precision of the difference $f(a+h)-f(a)$ will vanish. In my case defining $h$ as

$$h=\frac{\log_2(|a|)}{2^n}$$

reduces the problem to finding optimal value of $n$ which is equal for all the parameters. For this purpose I compute numerical approximations for all partial derivatives with $n$ running from 15 to 60 (I compute with high `WorkingPrecision`) and see where the precision of these approximations becomes sufficient or maximal for all the partial derivatives.

### UPDATE: efficient use of `ND`

Thanks to [acl's great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29331/16) now it is clear that `ND` with `Terms->1` uses exactly the same finite difference formula:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
ND[f[u], u, x, Terms -> 1, Scale -> h, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity]
```

> (-f[x] + f[h + x])/h

But one should be careful here: increasing the number of terms leads to **division** of the step $h$ by powers of 2 in successive higher order terms:

```
ND[f[u], u, x, Terms -> 2, Scale -> h, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity] // Simplify
```

> -((3 f[x] - 4 f[h/2 + x] + f[h + x])/h)

```
ND[f[u], u, x, Terms -> 3, Scale -> h, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity] // Simplify
```

> (-21 f[x] + 32 f[h/4 + x] - 12 f[h/2 + x] + f[h + x])/(3 h)

It means that for getting the best possible approximation with `ND` one should estimate the step $h$ by the method described in the initial section of this answer, then multiply it by $2^{t-1}$ (where $t$ is the value of the `Terms` option of `ND`) and use as value for the `Scale` option.

These considerations can be compiled into a function with more intuitive and consistent behavior:

```
Options[myND] = {Terms -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision};
myND[expr_, x_, x0_, h_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ND[expr, x, x0, Scale -> h*2^(OptionValue[Terms]-1), opts]
```

Comment: This is exactly why I want to use ND, as it [is using more advanced methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html) which I hope are more stable than just [finite difference method of first order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Higher-order_methods). When I use correct `Scale` and stability can be improved by increasing the `Terms`.

Comment: Also I need a method, which works with complex variables. As I asked for reusage of ND I did not consider this point relevant before.

Comment: @Johu How do you estimate the correct `Scale` for usage with `ND`? This parameter is critical for getting correct derivatives but I have not found any information on this topic in the Documentation.

Comment: You probably know the general considerations of [round off vs rounding errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Practical_considerations_using_floating_point_arithmetic). So I have a guess from foreknowledge about my function and check if the result is insensitive (relevant change small) to `Scale` parameter (around the correct value). I guess the real error you make you can only estimate when you can also take the analytic derivative?

Comment: @Johu I do not take the analytic derivative. I just consider how derivatives depend on the parameter $n$. For relatively small $n$ this dependence is smooth and must asymptotically converge to the true value, but when $n$ becomes large the finite-precision errors introduce random noise which quickly becomes large with increasing $n$. It is easy to see where random noise becomes larger than the variation of a derivative with increasing $n$. So I choose an optimal $n$ at which random noise is an order of magnitude smaller than variation of derivatives with $n$.

Comment: @Johu Do you think that `Scale` basically has the same meaning as $h$ in the finite difference formula?

Comment: Yes, this is what I assumed. Sounds like another support ticket to Wolfram to ask for a improvement (this time in documentation).

We agree on how to estimate the h/Scale error. I just did not care for the optimal value. If error was small compared to value was good enough ("result is insensitive to `Scale`").

Comment: @Johu It was also my first thought but Wikipedia correctly [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Practical_considerations_using_floating_point_arithmetic) that typical choice of $h$ for double-precision arithmetics is of order $\sqrt{\varepsilon}x$ where the $\varepsilon$ is machine epsilon. It is not clear how it is related to default value `1` for the `Scale` option.

Comment: @Johu Documentation for `ND` and `Scale` says that `Scale` is the "size at which variations are expected" and that "the setting for `Scale` specifies the initial step size to use during Richardson extrapolation." I am not sure how to interpret these statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14777/discussion-between-johu-and-alexey-popkov).

Comment: @Johu and Alexei, belisarius and I played with this some [time ago](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29331/16), see if you find that useful.

Comment: @acl Big thanks! It clarifies the meaning of `Scale`. So @Johu is right: it means exactly the same as $h$ in the finite difference formula (with `Terms -> 1`). But it is important to know that it is **divided** by 2 in successive higher order terms: `ND[f[u], u, x, Terms -> 2, Scale -> .1]`.

Comment: I am puzzled now. Is the documentation just wrong? It has nothing to do with "Richardson's extrapolation"?

Comment: @Johu It seems that `ND` uses forward (and backward for negative `Scale`) difference formulas obtained from Richardson extrapolation, see terminology [here](http://dmpeli.math.mcmaster.ca/Matlab/Math4Q3/NumMethods/Lecture3-3.html) and the general formula [here](http://dafeda.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/numerical-differentiation-richardsons-extrapolation/).

Comment: @Johu and Alexey, forgot to mention that the code for `ND` is in `AddOns/Packages/NumericalCalculus/NLimit.m` so you can inspect it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to figure out how to generate  expressions like

```
ND[ND[ND[g[x, y, z], x, 1], y, 1], z, 1]
```

(taken from the first link you provided). If so, I think what you want is something along these lines:

```
ClearAll[nd];
SetAttributes[nd, HoldFirst];
Options[nd] = {Scale -> Automatic};
nd[func_, params__List, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[
   {vars = {params}[[All, 1]], inits = {params}[[All, 2]]},
   Fold[
    NDFunc[#1, Sequence @@ MapAt[Scale -> # &, #2, -1]] &,
    Apply[func, vars],
    Transpose@{
      vars,
      inits,
      OptionValue[Scale] /. 
       Automatic :> ConstantArray[1, Length@vars]}]];
```

So:

```
nd[f, {x, x0}, {y, y0}, {z, z0}]
```

> NDFunc[NDFunc[NDFunc[f[x, y, z], x, x0, Scale -> 1], y, y0, 
>     Scale -> 1], z, z0, Scale -> 1]

```
nd[f, {x, x0}, {y, y0}, {z, z0}, Scale -> {xscale, yscale, zscale}]
```

> NDFunc[NDFunc[NDFunc[f[x, y, z], x, x0, Scale -> xscale], y, y0, 
>     Scale -> yscale], z, z0, Scale -> zscale]

Comment: Thank you, but this is only half way there. See the discussion in either links on avoiding repeated ND calls before all parameters are numeric. I will also add this clarification in to the question.