# Using Numdifftools with ExternalEvaluate to calculate the Hessian

Tags: numerics, python

I need to compute numerically the Hessian of a numerical (scalar) function. Mathematica does not have a numerical Hessian routine (funny thing..) and so I am using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29060/462) implementation. However, though simple and fast, it is not very robust and I would like to use [Numdifftools](https://pypi.org/project/Numdifftools/). How can I compute the Hessian using the Python `nd.Hessian` routine? My function takes a vector of arbitrary length as argument and cannot take complex numbers.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43513/how-to-work-with-experimentalnumericalfunction) post may be of interest...

Comment: @ilian Thanks! With ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` I can indeed compute the Hessian numerically. It seems to work fine. However, it is undocumented and I do not know if it is as robust as Numdifftools. In the latter *[...] Finite differences are used in an adaptive manner, coupled with a Richardson extrapolation methodology to provide a maximally accurate result. [...]*

Comment: I created a [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173540/462) regarding the use of ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` to compute the Hessian.