# How is the Hessian computed using ``Experimental`NumericalFunction``?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, implementation-details, undocumented

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54877/462) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/462) it was explained how to use `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` to compute the Hessian of a numerical function. I would like to know how this undocumented function works; in particular if it is as robust as [Numdifftools](https://pypi.org/project/Numdifftools/), in which *[...] Finite differences are used in an adaptive manner, coupled with a Richardson extrapolation methodology to provide a maximally accurate result. [...]*

One could consider the following test code:

```
d = 3;
vecF = {1, 2, 3};
g[vec_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := vec.vec;
h[vec_] := vec.vec;
```

where `g` is a numerical function while `h` is suitable for symbolic evaluation. The Hessian is then obtained in the two cases using the following code:

```
Block[{e = 0},
  {f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[
  Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, d}], g[Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, d}]], {}, 
  Hessian -> {Automatic, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2},EvaluationMonitor :> e++];
  f["Hessian"[vecF]], e}
]
(*{{{2., 0., 0.}, {0., 2.00001, 0.}, {0., 0., 2.00001}}, 24}*)
```

and

```
Block[{e = 0},
  {f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[
  Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, d}], h[Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, d}]], {}, 
  Hessian -> {Automatic, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2},EvaluationMonitor :> e++];
  f["Hessian"[vecF]], e}
]
(*{{{2., 0., 0.}, {0., 2., 0.}, {0., 0., 2.}}, 0}*)
```

When evaluating the Hessian of `g` Mathematica uses `FiniteDifference` as method (with 24 evaluations of the function), while when evaluating the Hessian of `h` it uses `Symbolic` and `DifferenceOrder` is ignored. So, is it possible to know what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 3):

*Converting former comments to an (incomplete) answer.*

Well, in the first case, you supress symbolic evaluation by using the pattern `_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)`. So Mathematica has to switch to numeric differentiation. In the second case, Mathematica is clever enough to differentiate with respect to the symbolic variables that you supplied, e.g. this way: `D[h[Table[x[i], {i, d}]], {Table[x[i], {i, d}], 2}]`. I am not completely sure, but I think that `` Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction `` compiles the Jacobian and the Hessian; since it probably uses reals (doubles) to do so, the result of `f["Hessian"[vecF]]` is automatically cast to reals.

The code in EvaluationMonitor gets evaluated only if the 0th derivative (e.g., `f[vecF]`) is evaluated. But when `f["Hessian"[vecF]]` is called, then `f[vecF]` will only be called if numerical differentiation is activated (which is only the case for your first example).

Comment: thanks but what i would like to know is how the numerical differentiation works, especially regarding the choice of the steps for the finite differences evaluation

Comment: That's good question. Since it  is about internals, I cannot say more. But maybe somebody else can provide more detail...