# Second derivative using ND

Tags: numerics

I have a function g=f(x,t). The function "g" came from a numerical integration:

```
g[x_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[tt[x,r,t],{r,rmin,rmax}]
```

and tt(x,r,t) came from a data file.

How to plot the second derivative of g(x,t) with respect to "t" for a fixed "x" using the ND command?

[image]

For the first derivative, I can use:

```
ListPlot[Table[{y, ND[g[y, t], t, 15]}, {y, 50, 200, 3}]]
```

[image]

What about the second derivative? The query ["numerical partial derivative"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/numerical-partial-derivative) have no answer for the second derivative with respect to the same variable.

Comment: It's been awhile since I took calculus...  but I'm pretty sure you can take the derivative with respect to t before you integrate with respect to r, as long as rmin, and rmax don't depend on t, (Leibniz rule?). Then I'd do `NIntegrate[D[tt[x,r,t],{t,2}], {r,rmin,rmax}]`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans, in fact it is only an example.  My function is more complex than the example.

Comment: You can specify the order of the derivative in the `ND` function with `ND[f[x,y], {x, order}, x0]`.